# C# How to populate richbox based on combobox selection pulling option from sql

Tags: c#

I'm trying to update the contents of a richtext box based upon the value selected in the comobox. It's pulling the PartnerName and Response from SQL as seen below;

Currently can only get it to pull one of the Partner Names and it's response. What am I missing?

```
       string connectionString = 
       VendorFinder.Properties.Settings.Default.VendorFinderConnectionString;

        SqlDataReader dr;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT PartnerName, Response FROM 
        dbo.ResponseMessage", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            comboBox3.Items.Add(dr.GetValue(0));
            richTextBox1.Text = dr["Response"].ToString();
            dr.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Record Found. Please try again", "Vendor 
            Finder", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling dr.Read() only one time so in order to get all data i am putting it in while loop

Read() method act as cursor when you call it moves to next location in data
,so you have to keep calling it util you get all of your data

```
string connectionString = 
       VendorFinder.Properties.Settings.Default.VendorFinderConnectionString;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT PartnerName, Response FROM 
    dbo.ResponseMessage", con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if(dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            comboBox3.Items.Add(dr.GetValue(0));
            richTextBox1.Text = dr["Response"].ToString();
        }
        dr.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Record Found. Please try again", "Vendor 
        Finder", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

Comment: Now I see it, it's obvious. However, it doesn't update the richtextbox when different options are selected from the combobox...

Comment: it's working in that it now pulls the correct Partner Names. However, when I select lets say Partner 3 its not pull the correct response message for that Partner. Is it in need of an if statement?

Comment: @WHoward if(dr.HasRows) only checks if there are any rows available or not. so if you want you can remove it. while do the job for you.